# Playing video with TextureView, how to use Matrix to crop a video that specifies RectF?

Tags: crop

Using TextureView to play video, users can choose RectF for cropping and preview playback. I am using Matrix postScale for scaling, but there are some issues.

I have seen some examples, but they are based on fixed point scaling and then fill the entire View, but did not display the video in RectF mode.

```
           mEditAction.setCropWidth(actualCropRect.width());
            mEditAction.setCropHeight(actualCropRect.height());
            float scaleX = mVideoWidth / viewWidth;
            float scaleY  = mVideoHeight / viewHeight;
            mEditAction.setCropX(actualCropRect.left);
            mEditAction.setCropY(actualCropRect.top);
            mEditAction.setCropScaleX(scaleX);
            mEditAction.setCropScaleY(scaleY);


            Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
            matrix.setScale(scaleX, scaleY, actualCropRect.left, actualCropRect.top);
            videoTextureView.setTransform(matrix);

             FrameLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams((int) (actualCropRect.width()), (int) (actualCropRect.height()));
             layoutParams.gravity = Gravity.CENTER;
             videoTextureView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
```

I use the above code, but sometimes the clipping matrix is wrong